# BizTalk 2013 Verify auto-generated web message deployed correctly

Tags: soap, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I've got a SOAP service that I'm connecting to using the WCF-Custom adapter. I've generated the xsd and web-message multipart message types using .NET 2.0 *Add Web-Reference*

I'm getting the standard BizTalk message

> Finding the document specification by message type
>   `"http://myNamespace#webMessageName"` failed. Verify the schema deployed
>   properly.

Usually, I look in my application schemas in BizTalk Server Admin console and verify the schemas. As these are web messages where do I look to verify that these have deployed correctly?

Comment: One point to clarify, you should be useing the BizTalk WCF Service Consuming Wizard, not Add Web Reference.

Comment: @boatseller I intended to but I get an object reference not set error when I try. I found others with similar issues suggested to use the 2.0 web reference

Answer (score 1):

Did you Deploy the Solution/Project with the Schemas?  They must appear in BizTalk Administrator just like any other Schema.

That they are SOAP or came from Add Web Reference doesn't matter at runtime.  A Schema is a Schema.

Comment: Yes, I thought that this was the case. I get all the complex schema from the Reference.xsd files but none of the web message types from Reference.odx show

Comment: The types that are defined in Reference.xsd would appear in the Schemas list but the Port Types in the .odx are different and would never appear.  You have to make sure whatever .xsd that defines http://myNamespace#webMessageName is deployed in some Assembly.

Comment: The Reference.xsd files only contain schema for the messages in the service that include complex types. The wrapper request and response messages appear in Orchestration View in Multi-part message types but are not deployed as schema. I guess I'll have to manually define the messages that wrap simple types?