# BizTalk 2013 error - Invalid envelope namespace + other issues

Tags: xml, web-services, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I've been attempting to get a BizTalk orchestration connecting to an external axis2 web service for a couple of days with various issues.

The steps I've taken are:

1. **Generated schema for service** The *Add Generated Items -> Consume WCF Service* threw a null exception so I had to use the .NET 2.0 *Add Web-reference* to generate xsd and an odx.
2. **Manually create simple message schemas** As asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611307/biztalk-2013-verify-auto-generated-web-message-deployed-correctly/22611421) I created the schema for the simple request and response messages not auto-generated.
3. **Set up port** I've tried *WCF-Custom*, *WCF-BasicHttp* and *Http*

I always get the below message when attempting to receive the response:

```
Inner exception: Invalid envelope namespace

Exception type: SoapException
Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.BizTalk.Engine
Target Site: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ReadSoapException(System.Xml.XmlReader)
The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured

   at Microsoft.BizTalk.ExceptionUtil.ReadSoapException(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.SoapExceptionMsg.SoapExceptionFormatter.Deserialize(XLANGMessage msg, Stream stm)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.SoapExceptionMsg.get_TheException()
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.BTXLogicalPortBinding.VerifyMessage(Envelope env, String typeName, Context cxt, OperationInfo op)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.BTXPortBase.VerifyTransport(Envelope env, Int32 operationId, Context ctx)
```

The service throws SOAP exceptions but the messages (tested via browser and Fiddler) do not get returned with a SOAP envelope wrapper.

The other oddity is that in Fiddler the messages include some strange characters in the body. In most instances:

```
70
{expected message}
0
```

**Are my issues due to:**

- The service configuration
- The way I have set up the adapters -where have I specified that the response is expected to be within a SOAP envelope?
- The manual addition of the response schema. If this is incorrect how do I get the web message types deployed?
- Those unexpected characters - I tried the AutoResponder function of Fiddler with the characters removed but I get an IO exception (connection closed)
- Other...?

Comment: "do not get returned with a SOAP envelope" Are you saying that it's not a SOAP Service then?  If the endpoint is not returning SOAP, nothing in BizTalk will make it SOAP.

Comment: @boatseller No it's not although they return SOAP exceptions! It's the WCF adapters which are expecting a SOAP envelope and complaining because there is none

Comment: @boatseller I'm unsure what part of my setup has caused the treatment of this service as SOAP

Comment: Add Web Reference assumes SOAP.  The Adapters aren't actually Type specific.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is confirm with the axis2 team if this a really a SOAP service or some thing else.  If it's not fully SOAP compliant, the wizards won't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was testing using the Http endpoint instead of the SOAP endpoint. Doh!

I now have other problems ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686531/biztalk-wcf-custom-binding-to-use-for-soap-1-2-with-basic-authentication) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687367/biztalk-0-parameter-web-message-not-being-sent-in-request)) with choosing which binding to use with SOAP 1.1 or 1.2 and empty envelopes.