# BizTalk - WCF-Custom binding to use for SOAP 1.2 with basic authentication

Tags: wcf, soap, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a web service to consume in BizTalk which exposes both SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 endpoints and is secured with Basic Http Authentication.

I'm using the WCF-Custom adapter and trying to use SOAP 1.2.

[This comparison table shows that I cannot have the combination of basic Http authentication AND SOAP 1.2 and I'll have to use 1.1 and basicHttpBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind)

Will any of the other WS-* bindings allow me to do what I want? I would prefer to use SOAP 1.2 because it will, presumably*, be around longer than 1.1.

*may be misguided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe you are misguided.

What that table and article is saying is that the WCF protocal wants to send the credentials securely either by having a secure transport or encrypting the message payload.

You can use basic authentication with WCF-Custom and Basic Authentication.
Set the Binding type to wsHttpBinding, under WSHttpBidingElement, Security, Transport, set the clientCredentialType to Basic.

Comment: Yes, this only works if I use HTTPS, otherwise the Authorization header is not sent and I get a 401. I need to be able to inspect the requests and responses in Fiddler so need to be able to use HTTP. Once I move away from unit testing I can switch to HTTPS, SOAP 1.2 and wsHttpBinding. For now I will have to stick with basicHttpBinding